# Is group by good for this use case?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table that has user_id and role_id. I want to group user_id: 1 which also can multiple roles and In the end, I want to show count. Like for this user_id, there are 7 roles.

How can I achieve this in raw SQL query?

Comment: `select user_id, count(role) from MyTable group by user_id;`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, count(role_id) c
FROM atable
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for *typical* `group by`:

```
 select user_id, 
        count(role_id) 
   from MyTable
```

group by user_id;

here we `group` all records within `MyTable` by their `user_id` and then count all non null `roled_id` within each group. Depending on *how* `role_id` should be count you may want to put

```
  count(all role_id)
```

to count `null` `role_id` as well as not `null` ones

```
  count(distinct role_id)
```

to count `distinct` `role_id` in each group.